# Build a project while working on 2 different locations

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have a laravel project on my work, but i also want to work at home on this project. I can sync the files with github so thats not the problem. But my question is if you can at a online mysql database to a local laravel project? And how do you do that?

Otherwise i have to switch between databases and thats not ideal.

If you have other suggestions how i can do this, let met know please.

Comment: If I where you I would create a production and a develop database. If you get an migration you have a big chance you screw up your live environment...

Comment: Hoe kan ik het best z'n develop database maken, want ik heb wel een hosting maar als via plesk daar een database aanmaak zegt hij dat de host van de database localhost:3306 is

Comment: Well the main language over here is English but if you got a database on a webserver you can use the IP of that webserver to connect it to on port 3306. If you got a domain connected to it you can also do madebynees.nl:3306. Else you need to contact your webhost for the IP

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can give to this sort of question is:

Host the database on a live server and use it in both projects.